# Convert Raycast from 3D to 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hi im trying to convert a code that work on 3D project to get gameobject which i click on my mouse to work on 2D since im now doing a 2D project

```
public class SetTower : MonoBehaviour {

    public int selected;
    public GameObject[] towers;
    public float[] prices;
    public GameObject tile;

    private Money moneyScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        moneyScript = GameObject.Find("GameLogic").GetComponent<Money>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 20))
        {
            if(hit.transform.tag == "Tile")
            {
                tile = hit.transform.gameObject;
            }
            else
            {
                tile = null;
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && tile != null)
            {
                TileTaken tileScript = tile.GetComponent<TileTaken>();

                if(!tileScript.isTaken && moneyScript.money >= prices[selected])
                {
                    moneyScript.money -= prices[selected];
                    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(tile.transform.position.x, tile.transform.position.y);

                    tileScript.tower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towers[selected], pos, Quaternion.identity);
                    tileScript.isTaken = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay` with `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint`, `Physics.Raycast` with `Physics2D.Raycast`, and `RaycastHit` with `RaycastHit2D`. Make sure to also switch to *2D Colliders*. For example, *Box Collider* should be replaced with *Box Collider 2D*.

```
public class SetTower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int selected;
    public GameObject[] towers;
    public float[] prices;
    public GameObject tile;

    private Money moneyScript;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        moneyScript = GameObject.Find("GameLogic").GetComponent<Money>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray, Vector2.zero, 20);

        if (hit)
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Tile")
            {
                tile = hit.transform.gameObject;
            }
            else
            {
                tile = null;
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && tile != null)
            {
                TileTaken tileScript = tile.GetComponent<TileTaken>();

                if (!tileScript.isTaken && moneyScript.money >= prices[selected])
                {
                    //moneyScript.money -= prices[selected];
                    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(tile.transform.position.x, tile.transform.position.y);

                    //tileScript.tower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towers[selected], pos, Quaternion.identity);
                    //tileScript.isTaken = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```